# How do I work with the system clock / time in xamarin forms?

Tags: android, forms, xamarin, time, clock

for a school project i'm making an app. The app is supposed to keep track of the time that you spend working on something specific. For example when i'm going to start my work shift, I would press a (start)button so the timer starts off and counts how much I've worked until i press a stop button.

I've got the xaml ready with all the buttons and labels.

My main problem is the timer. I would like to have a stopwatch underneath my start button, that shows the elapsed time. I've been looking for many many hours on github, stackoverflow, google and youtube and haven't found a solution.

If it isn't easy/possible to implement a stopwatch, i would at least need the app to check for the system time when the start and stop buttons are clicked, to calculate the difference in time.

So far I haven't been able to get any of those functions working.
Thanks in advance! - MagSky

Answer (score 2):

.NET has a built in [Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) class you can use

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();

// do some work here

stopWatch.Stop();
// Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
```

to display a Timer in the UI, use [System.Timers.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) instead

```
int secs = 0;
// fire an event every 1000 ms
Timer timer = new Timer(1000);
// when event fires, update Label
timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => { secs++; myLabel.Text = $"{secs} seconds"; };
// start the timer
timer.Start();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This seems to work since no errors occur. For other people who want to use the timer class: make sure to include 'using System.Diagnostics;' to the class that uses the stopwatch class.
Do you have any suggestions how to update the 'elapsed Time Label' every second so the elapsed time wil be shown constantly?
At least I can see the elapsed time after pressing the stop button, so we're on the right track.

Comment: see my 2nd example

Comment: I can't get it working. If I put that exact code in my startButton method
(sender, e) gives an error:
A local or parameter named 'sender' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter | 
And: 
A local or parameter named 'e' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter |

And when I paste this into a completely new button and label, the app crashes on click

Comment: a, that error is telling you that you're reusing variable names in the same scope.  Just use different names.  b, if you want to start the timer in a click event handler, only the Start() needs to be in the handler, the rest should be declared at a class level